# Average of the inverse distance between two points in a uniform ball

Tags: uniform-distribution, inverse-function, average

I'd like to compute the average of the inverse distance between two different points $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2)$ in a ball $B(0,R)$. In particular, I'd like to calculate the following integral (when it converges)

$\int_{B(0,R)} \int_{B(0,R)} \frac{1}{|x-y|} dx dy$

In general, this integral doesn't converge, but I could assume that $|x-y|>\epsilon$ for some small $\epsilon>0$.

I found an estimate from below and from above and I computed it. In particular,

$ \int_{B(0,R)} \int_{B(0,R)} \frac{1}{2 max\{|x_1-y_2|, |x_2-y_2|\}} dx dy \leq \\
\int_{B(0,R)} \int_{B(0,R)} \frac{1}{|x-y|} dx dy \leq \\ \int_{B(0,R)} \int_{B(0,R)} \frac{1}{max\{|x_1-y_2|, |x_2-y_2|\}} dx dy$

The problem is interesting because it is useful to compute the following integral
$\int_{B(0,R)} \int_{B(0,R)} \frac{1}{|x-y|^\lambda} dx dy$
for some $\lambda$, that can be interpret as a long range interaction between two particles.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I found this an interesting question and I've computed the mean reciprocal distance between two points inside a sphere of radius $R$. I can't post the answer until the question is brought up to [site standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959): say what you might have tried, what tools you have available, where you found this problem, etc.

Comment: You might start by showing that one integration converges for each $y$. Then move onto integrating in $y$.

Comment: Now can you answer? Thanks

Comment: Sorry it took so long.  It took a while to get the diagrams just right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Distance to a Sphere in a Direction Offset from the Closest**

Consider the following diagram

[image]

Define $r=OP$ and $R=OS=OQ$. Then the Pythagorean Theorem says
$$
\begin{align}
MS
&=MQ\tag{1a}\\[3pt]
&=\sqrt{OQ^2-OM^2}\tag{1b}\\
&=\sqrt{R^2-r^2\sin^2(\theta)}\tag{1c}
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore,
$$
MP=r\cos(\theta)\tag2
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
PQ&=MQ-MP\tag{3a}\\[3pt]
&=-r\cos(\theta)+\sqrt{R^2-r^2\sin^2(\theta)}\tag{3b}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
PS&=MS+MP\tag{4a}\\[3pt]
&=r\cos(\theta)+\sqrt{R^2-r^2\sin^2(\theta)}\tag{4b}\\
&=-r\cos(\theta-\pi)+\sqrt{R^2-r^2\sin^2(\theta-\pi)}\tag{4c}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, we have shown the following

**Theorem:** Given a point $P$ at a distance $r$ from the center of a sphere of radius $R$,
the distance $\Delta$ from $P$ to the sphere in a direction at angle $\theta$ from the direction
to the closest point of the sphere is
$$
\Delta=-r\cos(\theta)+\sqrt{R^2-r^2\sin^2(\theta)}\tag5
$$

---

**Mean Reciprocal Distance in a Given Solid Angle**

[image]

Given a [solid angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle) $\Omega$,
the volume of the solid slab is $\Omega r^2\,\mathrm{d}r$, where $r$ is the distance
of the slab from the vertex. Thus, the volume-weighted integral of the reciprocal
distance from the vertex is
$$
\int_0^\Delta\frac{\Omega r^2\,\mathrm{d}r}r=\frac{\Omega\Delta^2}2\tag6
$$
where $\Delta$ is the maximum distance of the slabs from the vertex.

---

**Computing the Mean Reciprocal Distance from a Given Point**

Let $P$ be a point at a distance $r$ from $O$, the center of a sphere of radius $R$,
The set of points on the sphere at distance $\Delta$ from $P$ are along the edge
of the base of a [right-circular cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone)
with angle $\theta$. Formula $(5)$ applies to any planar slice of the sphere containing $OP$.

[image]

The solid angle subtended by the infinitesimal wedge of a cone between angles
$\theta$ and $\theta+\mathrm{d}\theta$ is
$$
\mathrm{d}\Omega=2\pi\sin(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta\tag7
$$
Thus, using $\Delta=-r\cos(\theta)+\sqrt{R^2-r^2\sin^2(\theta)}$, we integrate $\frac{\Delta^2\mathrm{d}\Omega}2$ (from $(6)$):
$$
\begin{align}
\iiint_{|x|\le R}\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{|P-x|}
&=\frac12\int_0^\pi\left(-r\cos(\theta)+\sqrt{R^2-r^2\sin^2(\theta)}\right)^22\pi\sin(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta\tag{8a}\\
&=\pi\int_{-1}^1\left(-ru+\sqrt{R^2-r^2+r^2u^2}\right)^2\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{8b}\\
&=\pi\frac{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}^3}r\int_{-\frac{r}{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}}^{\frac{r}{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}}\left(-u+\sqrt{1+u^2}\right)^2\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{8c}\\
&=\pi\frac{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}^3}r\int_{-\frac{r}{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}}^{\frac{r}{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}}\left(1+2u^2\right)\mathrm{d}u\tag{8d}\\
&=\pi\frac{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}^3}r\left(\frac{2r}{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}+\frac{\frac43r^3}{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}^3}\right)\tag{8e}\\
&=2\pi\left(R^2-r^2\right)+\frac{4\pi}3r^2\tag{8f}\\
&=2\pi R^2-\frac{2\pi}3r^2\tag{8g}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(8a):}$ combine $(6)$ and $(7)$
$\text{(8b):}$ substitute $u=\cos(\theta)$
$\text{(8c):}$ substitute $u\mapsto \frac{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}ru$
$\text{(8d):}$ after squaring the integrand, the odd part is cancelled
$\text{(8e):}$ integrate
$\text{(8f):}$ simplify
$\text{(8g):}$ simplify

Dividing by $\frac{4\pi}3R^3$ gives the average reciprocal distance from a point at distance $r$ from the center of a sphere with radius $R$:
$$
\frac3{2R}-\frac1{2R}\left(\frac rR\right)^2\tag9
$$

---

**Compute the Mean Reciprocal Distance Between Two Points**

The average reciprocal distance between two random points in a sphere of radius $R$ is
$$
\frac3{4\pi R^3}\int_0^R\left(\frac3{2R}-\frac1{2R}\left(\frac rR\right)^2\right)4\pi r^2\,\mathrm{d}r=\frac6{5R}\tag{10}
$$

---

**Empirical Verification**

Generating five runs of $4000$ random points in a unit sphere and taking the average of the reciprocals of the distances between all pairs, I got $1.19412,1.2,1.19647,1.20498,1.20042$. These are all close to the theoretical average of $\frac65=1.2$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have a question: why did you divide by the volume of the ball twice? Maybe you wanted to divide by it and then moltiplicate by it?

Comment: We are integrating over the ball twice, once for each of the two points.

Comment: you wrote that the volume of the solid slab is Omega r^2 dr with r between [0,Delta], but if I focus on the first picture, this volume does not coincide with the part of the sphere volume (between PQ and its symmetrical)  because the area on the surface of the sphere is different from the “area of basis” of the solid slab that you considered, right?

Comment: Note that $\theta$ and $\mathrm{d}\theta$ are measured from $P$, not from $O$. Think of the highlighted volume in the second diagram as a ring of pyramids from the first diagram.

Comment: can you give me a geometrical interpretation of what you are computing in equation 8a?Why the left hand side can be computed using the right hand side? How does he get the formula?(i know he uses equation 6 but why?) Thank you very much

Comment: I have expanded $(7)$ and the text preceding $(8)$. $\mathrm{d}\Omega$ is the solid angle of the infinitesimal wedge of a cone in the preceding diagram, and we sum the contributions from $(6)$, $\frac{\Delta^2\mathrm{d}\Omega}2$, in $\text{(8a)}$.